# Python3.x: Format Float to 2 Digits, Limit to 3 Decimal places

Tags: python, time, floating-point, format

I have seen many questions about formatting `floats` and limiting decimal places, but I have not seen both done at once. I want the values for my variable `seconds` to always be represented as SS.mmm.

I have

```
t = int(input('time?: '))
seconds = (t / 1000) % 60
minutes = (t // (1000 * 60)) % 60
hours = (t // (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24
```

I want to print `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` so that it will **always** follow HH:MM:SS.mmm

My attempt:

```
print('{}:{}:{}'.format("%02d" % hours, "%02d" % minutes, ("%.3f" % seconds).zfill(2)))
```

I end up getting HH:MM:S.mmm sometimes. I need there to be two seconds digits even if there is a leading zero.

Comment: recommend you read [this](https://pyformat.info/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do the following with `.format()`:

```
print('{:0>2d}:{:0>2d}:{:06.3f}'.format(hours,minutes,seconds))
```

In particular, `0>2d` forces the integers `hours` and `minutes` to be of length 2. Further, `06.3f` implies that the entire float representation should be 6 characters long (including the `'.'`) and have 3 decimal places to the right of the period.